# Load UIView from XIB incorrect size

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm new to iOS 8, I tried to load a UIView from XIB file with auto layout and size classes option are enabled. I use Inferred size XIB with default size is 600 x 600. But on the simulator the size of view is not fit screen size, it still be 600 x 600 and doesn't fit the screen size like this, it's much bigger than the screen on width:
[image]

But when I use View Controller widget, it has Resize of NIB option, and it work fine to fit the screen size. Can anybody suggest what should I do to resize UIView to fit screen size? Thank you very much, guys!

Update:
Here is how I call it:
[image]

And constraint I use:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use autolayout and set constraint. It is better choice if you need to support multiple device.

Try to figure out with these 3 images first. Then I am discussing one by one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGAQu.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sWc1.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbTWP.jpg

Comment: I've set it already! But the problem is the view is not resized, that's root cause of this problem.

Comment: some where you add you call. i can see it/ give screenshot

Comment: I updated with screenshot, please give a look and suggest me how to fix it, thank you

Comment: do you need to design for multiple device

Comment: yep! i design it as universal app. But now I need solution how to resize UIView to fit individual screen

Comment: it is a little bit difficult. so you need to study. After a some while i am giving you a example tutorial

Comment: you guys don't understand me, I did not mention about story board and use View Controller widget! Thank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89512/discussion-between-jamil65able-and-phong-nguyen).